# Nginx: Using rewrite together with try_files

Tags: file, nginx, url-rewriting

I'm trying to use `rewrite` alongside `try_files`. Ideally, I would like Nginx to try the raw URI first. If that doesn't work, then try a controller `/controllers/$1.php`. Finally, just redirect to the index. This is what I have so far (I've sacrificed the ideal order mentioned above for succinctness):

```
location / {
  if (-f /controllers/$uri) {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /controllers/$1.php last;
    return 403;
  }
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}
```

This doesn't seem to be working, though. Any ideas?

Comment: It seems you do not understand how the rewrite module works. Please, read: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html But for your case you do not need the rewrite module at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /controllers$uri.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php;

        #
        # fastcgi/proxy_pass php configuration
        #
    }
}
```

- http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil
- http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls

Comment: Worked like a charm! Yeah, it's time to sit down and give that documentation a thorough reading...